# Launch excapse system for satellite payloads?

Tags: artificial-satellite, failure, launch-vehicle, commercial, launch-escape-system

Once a rocket lifts off, there is usually no abort mode that does not involve the destruction of the rocket, and on a satellite launch, the payload.

Therefore, expendeble satellite launchers are quite expensive in part due measures taken to enhance reliability for their valuable payloads. This usually leads to satellite operators choosing lightweight, expensive hardware to reduce the launch cost.

Crewed flights always have some way to save the payload in case of failure.

What if a launch failure was not the end of a payload? What if an expendable LV was designed with less emphasis on reliability, but with a launch escape system that could return the payload safely to Earth in case of a launch failure?

As explained [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/why-dont-unmanned-launch-vehicles-include-launch-escape-system-for-payload), a full escape tpwer is probaby not practical.

What kind of a system would be practical to return the payload without damaging it? (Eg:- capsule, heat shielded fairing, repurposed second stage etc)

When would this system be able to save the payload? (eg:pad explosion, low altitude first stage failure, high altitude second stage failure)

What would be the cost-saving design and operational choices (eg:- "big dumb booster" and "big dumb satellite" options) that would be opened by this reduced focus on launch reliability?

What would be the penalties (weight, cost, new failure modes, etc) of the system?