# What if satellites could be recovered during a launch failure?

Tags: design-alternative, failure, launch-vehicle, launch-escape-system

How heavy would a capsule have to be to return a satellite safely to earth in the event of a launch failure? Would a satellite survive the loads endured by astronauts during an abort? If not, is there any way to reduce them?

How much would such a capability influence booster design, construction, and operation to reduce cost otherwise spent to ensure reliability?

If it becomes unfeasible to provide full coverage, how useful would it be to cover during a first stage failure only? (Since this is when fairings are normally attached anyway)

Comment: If you successfully slow down the satellite with a parachute from several hundreds or thousands height down to the surface of water and the satellite splash down in the salt water you have to prevent the destruction of the satellite by the salt water corrosion. But a water tight and pressure resistant hull of a satellite in orbit would be a lot of wasted mass.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why don't unmanned launch vehicles include launch escape system for payload?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/why-dont-unmanned-launch-vehicles-include-launch-escape-system-for-payload)